# Access VBA: Find if computer username is an active user

Tags: ms-access, authentication, vba

I'm using Access 2013.

I want to disable buttons on some forms based on the user that is logged into the computer.

I'm using code from Dev Ashish to determine the name of the logged in user to the computer.

The username is stored in global variable LoggedInUser

I have a table called "Users" in which I am storing the login emails for the admins who need expanded functions. This table along with other fields has the following fields:
"Email" Short Text
"Active" yes/no

I want to check if the logged in user exists in the users table and if they are marked as Active.

I then want a global boolean variable called AuthUser to hold a true/false for if the user exists in the table and is active or not.

I think this might need to be done with a dlookup or dcount, but I just can't seem to make it work - any ideas on a solution?

Comment: What doesn't work? You refer to code that isn't working. Show some code please and error messages or explain what isn't working. A simple query using NetworkUsername API callwill give you what you need.

Comment: I have the code that gets me the username from the computer - I need to check that the username exists in the access table as an active admin user for the database. I can't work out how in VBA to make that query for if the name exists and if it is active :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown your query that doesn't work?

I can guess - and you can tell me I guessed wrong 
Here's something you can play with

```
dim rs as DAO.Recordset
strSQL = "SELECT Username from Users WHERE [Username] = """ & LoggedInUser & """ AND [Active]"
set rs = currentdb.openrecordset(strSQL)
AuthUser = Not rs.EOF
rs.close
```

Comment: dbmitch - no code, I had nothing remotly working... despite that YOU ARE BRILLIANT. This is just what I needed and perfect. Also, I think I see how this works, thank you very much!